# Context "this" is not kept at object methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I believe (may be I wrong) method definition at ECMA6 uses arrow functions (internally) and "this" (context) must be kept.
But

```
class Foo {
    methodOne() {
        console.log("MethodOne is called")
    }

    methodTwo() {
        console.log("MethodTwo is called");
        this.methodOne();
    }
}

var foo = new Foo();

var executing = function (someMethod) {someMethod()};

executing(foo.methodTwo)
```

It raises error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'methodOne' of undefined(…)"

So, either I understood specification incorrect or browsers (Chrome, FF) and nodejs does not support this yet?

Comment: Where in the spec does it say something like _"uses arrow functions (internally)"_ or  _"'this' (context) must be kept"_? And why should it have changed with ES6?

Comment: Arrow functions and method definitions are two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes in ES6 are just syntactic sugar over prototypal inheritance. This way the method declarations in the class are attached to the `prototype` object.

1) The problem in the example is in the way the function is invoked. To keep the context `this`, you still need **to invoke it as a method on an object**:

```
var foo = new Foo();

var executing = function (someMethod, context) {someMethod.apply(context)};

executing(foo.methodTwo, context);
```

2) But if you invoke it as **a regular function**, then you'll have this as `undefined` in strict mode:

```
 methodTwo() {
        console.log("MethodTwo is called");
        this.methodOne(); // <---- `this` is `undefined`
 }
```

---

`this` in a function call is determined by the way it is invoked:

1. as regular function (makes `this` as `undefined` or global object in non strict mode): `someMethod();` or `var m = foo.methodTwo; m();`
2. as a method on an object (makes `this` the object): `foo.methodTwo()`
3. as constructor (makes `this` the newly created object): `new Foo()`
4. indirect invocation (using `apply(newContext)` and `call(newContext)`): `someMethod.apply(context)`.

Notice that `bound()` method can modify the context before invocation. It will cancel any later context modifications on invocation for cases 1, 2 and 4. For constructor invocation the bound context is ignored and still used the newly created object.

Check [this nice post](http://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/) about the function context and invocation in JavaScript.

Comment: In the latter case, isn't it the global object instead of undefined?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich In strict mode undefined, in non strict global object.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin how do you get undefined if you are calling it as `foo.method`?

Comment: @The You're not calling `foo.method`, you're just taking the reference to function object. And later this object is invoked as regular function with `this` as `undefined`. Contrary to `foo.method()`: an method invocation on `foo` object.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin what do you mean under _regular function_? something like `method()`?

Comment: _"this in a function call is always determined by the way it is invoked"_ That's not correct. A function can be bound to a certain `this` value and arrow functions use the value of the surrounding environment.

Comment: @zeroflagL Thanks for the note. Made the clarification in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> So, either I understood specification incorrect or browsers (Chrome, FF) and nodejs does not support this yet?

Whichever part of the spec you read, you misunderstood it. Methods and arrow functions are two different things, and even if methods had arrow function semantics, you wouldn't get the behavior you expected (since arrow functions resolve `this` lexically).

No, methods work like normal function declararions/expressions wrt to `this`.

See also [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: You are right. I have read spec again and it becomes clear for me.